# Proyecto no encuentra referencias (dll)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net, librería, referencias

Tengo unas dll que necesito usar en mi solucion.
Probe crear nuevos proyectos y refenciar las dll y funcionan bien.
Probe agregar ese proyecto a la Solucion y funciona. (Aclaro esto para demostrar que el problema no es la dll)
El problema es que cuando hago referencia a esas dll desde mi proyecto original, compila sin problema. Pero luego al correrlo no  llega a entrar a la funcion que usa esas libreria. Dice que no las encuentra.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Cuales son las razones por la cual un proyecto podria no encontra las refencias?
Framework 4.7.2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: En lugar de poner una imagen con el código, sería mejor que muestres los resultados de compilación y depuración.

Comment: la tienes referenciada?

Comment: clic derecho en References y add references, buscas las dll que necesitas y mira de nuevo

Comment: Hola, Si las tengo refernciadas. Incluso las utilizo en otros proyectos y funciona perfecto. Es algo en particular de este proyecto que no las toma. Alguna configuracion tiene el proyecto que hace que no la reconozca.

Comment: Ger, ya probe y nada.

Comment: Podrías intentar eliminarlas de referencias, luego eliminar el Using de tus referencias y luego volver a agregarlas normalmente. (Te recomiendo que agregues el .dll de proyectos en los que sabes que funcionan) 
Personalmente a veces me pasa, se me pierden las referencias   .

Answer (score 1):

Principalmente parece ser un problema de las plataformas de compilación de las dll que utilizan tu proyecto, es decir tienes las otras bibliotecas/soluciones compiladas en distintas plataformas (x86/Debug) diferentes al proyecto que quieres compilar, tendrías que unificar las plataformas de compilación de todos tus proyectos en x86 o Debug.

Haz segundo click sobre tu proyecto solución **>** Propiedades **>** Propiedades de Configuración y verificar que todos los proyectos estén compilados en la misma plataforma.

Luego, prueba borrando la carpeta bin de tu proyecto y compilando toda la solución, tendría que haberse solucionado.

Un saludo.